# Is there a readily available solution for displaying a cookie consent GDPR compliant message on a MediaWiki website?

Tags: cookies, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, cookieconsent, gdprconsentform

I guess the question is self explanatory. In case no readily solutions are available, which would be the easiest way to implement the message (except from editing MediaWiki's skins and adding the code, which would possibly require redoing the job after [upgrades](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading))?

Answer (score 2):

There's an extension, [CookieWarning](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CookieWarning), which does exactly that. It shows a message to a new user, that the site uses cookies, which can be acknowledged by clicking "OK". You can also optionally configure a link ("More information"), which can lead to a full Cookie Policy document on your site (it can be a link somewhere in the Wiki or an external page as well).

You can, if you want, change the text that is showed to users by editing the interface message `cookiewarning-info` (`https://yourwiki.com/wiki/MediaWiki:cookiewarning-info`).

Disclaimer: My answer might be opinionated, as I'm one of the authors of this extension.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

I have already seen the extension. While a warning is GDPR compliant as long as a site has only essential cookies (and MediaWiki falls into that category), it is not GDPR compliant in case tracking scripts or advertising scripts have been added to the website, because GDPR requires user consent before the scripts' activation, something like this for example: https://www.freeprivacypolicy.com/cookie-consent/

It would be great if the extension you mentioned was enhanced with this extra, but law required functionality.

Comment: That's true. However, it's pretty hard for an extension to block other extension code easily. However, this discussion would go too widely here. Would you be able to open an issue in the issue tracker for the extension with your request? https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/project/view/2240/

Comment: I don't know how hard that would be for a MediaWiki's extension, but it definitely is common practice in many websites, in many implementations of privacy warnings, as the one I mentioned in my previous message as an example.

I will check Phabricator and I will make a request there.